# Rails has_many association results in a "no such column" error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I am following the guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
and I have created

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy
end



class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

but executing `@order = @customer.orders.create()` results in

> unknown attribute: customer_id

Do you know why does this error occurs? And more importantly Is there a hidden reason for all the guides for has_many to drive you insane with showing this example, but non of them to be actually working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add customer_id column to orders table.

For that you have to run the migration -

rails g migration add_customer_id_to_orders customer_id:integer

then

rake db:migrate

Comment: Thanks. This will probably answer my question. Still trying to understand why is there such a gap between your model and you db and why adding the needed meta-information in the model is not enough to make the application work...

Comment: sorry i m not getting you question..please explain what you trying to say

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to add a `customer_id` column to your orders table.

ActiveRecord doesn't know which customer to fetch for the relating order.

Try `rails g migration AddCustomerIdToOrders customer_id:integer` (don't forget db:migrate).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to run your migrations. From the console and within the root directory of your rails project, run `rake db:migrate` to ensure rails has generated all the backing tables and columns for your associations and models.

Comment: I have run rake db:migrate prior opening the console. After running rake db:migrate I have two tables - customers(id,create_at,updated_at) and orders(id,create_at,updated_at).